# I am unable to remove profile in iPhone

Tags: iphone, apple-configurator

I have tried all the things but I am unable to remove the profile from my iPhone. The web clip has no removable type. So if you have any solutions then please answer me as fast as possible.

[image]

Comment: You cannot remove just a Web Clip. You need to back up a level and try to remove the whole profile.